# Add extra text to the copied text

Tags: java, android

I have this TextView in my application

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatusMsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_status_pad_top"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
         />
```

and its selectable ..when i select text and copy it i want to add extra text

example :

Test text

what i want is when i select the text and copy it :

Test text - Copied from xx app

how i can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a clipboardListener:

```
private boolean mSkipClip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager)mAct.getSystemService
            (Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    mClipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager
            .OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            if (mSkipClip) {
                mSkipClip = false;
            } else {
                // Append custom string
                ClipData clipData = new ClipData(mClipboard.getPrimaryClip());
                clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item("Copied from xx app"));
                mSkipClip = true;
                mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

*Notes:*

- `ClipData` class which is available only since API 16.
- Other classes and methods are available since API 11.
- When you update the clipboard data, the listener is called again. `mSkipClip` helps the listener skip such callbacks.
- When pausing your activity, make sure you remove the listener, as it will listen to clipboard activity on other activities and apps too.

Comment: thank you .. its work fine ..
just replace         clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item("Copied from xx app"));

with :
          mClipboard.setText(mClipboard.getText().toString() + "\n Copied from xx app");
and remove 
mClipboard.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(this);

Comment: @IbrahimQAl-Bzour The answer you suggested earlier, will work for a single copy only. If you're experiencing problems of copy multiplications, you need to delay re-adding the listener.

Comment: how i can delay the add listener ?

Comment: @IbrahimQAl-Bzour I've updated my answer with a flag that will prevent listener callbacks to self and now you don't need to remove/re-add the listener inside of itself.